# send message in MS Teams chat in-browser with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, microsoft-teams

While our University disabled API access, I thought I could try solving my problem with a Chrome Extension.

Background: I have built a monitoring app (nodeJS) that tracks student progress of their submitted work in GitHub. I can generate some tables with progress, but I need to manually send these to each and every student in a Teams chat. I was looking to automate this some more...

So I thought, while in a in-browser Teams chat with a student, let's find out if I can manipulate the current chat's messagebox with my own message and then hit send. All with Javascript.

I've managed to find out how to click the specific send button, but apparently MS Teams uses CKEDITOR, so I can't just edit the textbox (it's actually a div with data-tid="ckeditor" and a paragraph inside).

Does anyone know how I can change the value of that message box to let's say "Hello World" with injected Javascript through a custom Chrome Extension?

Answer (score 0):

This could be hard to implement in a chrome extension considering the security rules which browsers have, which are for our own internet security. Because we don't want any malicious chrome extension to auto fill our forms & auto submit. You should look for something like a headless browser (for eg. [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/)) for such requirements.

Comment: yeah, but I'm only using my own logged in webpage to do stuff. The chrome extension is only for myself. So I scrape the page to find the right HTML elements and just want to inject a text in a paragraph so to speak. Problem is, it is built with CKEDITOR and everything I tried didn't work. So that is nothing more than mimicking my own behaviour, but in a slightly automated way.
Puppeteer isn't an option because of MFA.